# Get reference to code-behind class instance from IValueConverter

Tags: c#, reference, code-behind, windows-phone-8

I have this code:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class SearchField : UserControl
    {
        public SearchStrategy Strategy { get; set; }
        public SearchField() { InitializeComponent(); }
    }

    public class TextToTipConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            SearchStrategy Strategy = // How do I get reference to SearchField.Strategy from here?

            return Strategy.parseInput<string> (value.ToString(), (first, inp) => Strategy.tipMap.ContainsKey(first) && inp.Length == 1 ? first + Strategy.tipMap[first] : "", AppResources.GeneralSearchTip);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
            object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Code in XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <controls:TextToTipConverter x:Key="TextToTip" />
</UserControl.Resources>
...
<TextBox x:Name="Search" Grid.Column="0" Canvas.ZIndex="1" 
                 Style="{StaticResource SearchBoxStyle}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />

<TextBox x:Name="Tip" Grid.Column="0" Canvas.ZIndex="0" IsReadOnly="True"
                 Style="{StaticResource SearchBoxStyle}" Opacity="0.5" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
                 Text="{Binding ElementName=Search, Converter={StaticResource TextToTip}, Path=Text}" />
```

`SearchField`'s `SearchStrategy Strategy` has some methods and fields that I need to access from `TextToTipConverter`.
How can I get to it?

Comment: I've run into a problem similar to this in the past.  What would be ideal is to bind your SearchStrategy object to ConverterParameter, but this is not possible since Binding is not a DependencyObject so ConverterParameter is not bindable.  What type of object is being passed into the Convert() method via the value parameter?

Comment: @RaySaltrelli I've updated post and included XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SearchField.xaml is the view and SearchField.xaml.cs is the code behind. You can read information about MVVM, databinding and ViewModel on msdn.
You can make a class called ViewModel on which you will bind your data. For instance, imagine the following class :

```
public class SearchViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public SearchStrategy Strategy { get; set; }
}
```

Your SearchField.xaml.cs will be :

```
public partial class SearchField : UserControl
{
    private SearchViewModel viewModel;

    public SearchField() 
    {
        this.viewModel = new SearchViewModel ();
        this.DataContext = this.viewModel;
    }
}
```

Now in your xaml,

```
TextBox x:Name="Search" Text="{Binding Text}"
```

will bind the data in the viewModel with the TextBox
And you will be able to do :

```
TextBox x:Name="Tip" Text="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource TextToTip}, Path=Text}"
```

In the converter, the parameter named value will be your view model on which you can get properties :

```
SearchViewModel vm = (SearchViewModel) value;
vm.Strategy;
vm.Text
```

I don't know if i'm clear.

Comment: Notice interface INotifyPropertyChanged that is implemented by my view model. Actually when you modify your property in the text block, it's automatically setted to your property Text in the view model. But if you wanna the TextBox change while the property is setted by another component, you have to raise the propertyChanged event. You can find information about it on msdn

Comment: Yeah, I've already read about it, thanks. Compiler actually required me to implement `PropertyChanged` event on `SearchViewModel`. And yes I do need to change binded values programmatically and have that reflected in UI so your proposed solution is really good.

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of binding your Tip text box directly to the Search text box, you could try creating a two-way binding between the Search text box and a property in a SearchFieldViewModel.  This will cause changes to the Search text box to be automatically pushed down into the SearchFieldViewModel.

Once the search string is in the SearchFieldViewModel, you can then bundle it along with the SearchStrategy into a TipViewModel and use the TipViewModel as the DataContext for your Tip text box.  See the code below.

**SearchField.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication.SearchField"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:TextToTipConverter x:Key="TextToTip" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <TextBox x:Name="Search" Grid.Column="0" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Text="{Binding Path=SearchString, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 Style="{StaticResource SearchBoxStyle}" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" />

        <TextBox x:Name="Tip" Grid.Column="0" Canvas.ZIndex="0" IsReadOnly="True"
                 Style="{StaticResource SearchBoxStyle}" Opacity="0.5" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
                 Text="{Binding Path=TipViewModel, Converter={StaticResource TextToTip}}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**SearchField.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class SearchField : UserControl
{
   public SearchField()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       this.Loaded += (s, e) => this.LayoutRoot.DataContext = new SearchFieldViewModel();
    }
}
```

**SearchFieldViewModel.cs**

```
public class SearchFieldViewModel
{
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
    public SearchStrategy SearchStrategy { get; set; }

    public TipViewModel TipViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return new TipViewModel
            {
                SearchString = this.SearchString,
                SearchStrategy = this.SearchStrategy
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**TipViewModel.cs**

```
public class TipViewModel
{
    public string SearchString { get; set; }
    public SearchStrategy SearchStrategy { get; set; }
}
```

**TextToTipConverter.cs**

```
public class TextToTipConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        TipViewModel tipViewModel = value as TipViewModel;
        SearchStrategy strategy = tipViewModel.SearchStrategy;
        string searchString = tipViewModel.SearchString;

        return Strategy.parseInput<string>(searchString , (first, inp) => strategy.tipMap.ContainsKey(first) && inp.Length == 1 ? first + strategy.tipMap[first] : "", AppResources.GeneralSearchTip);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's similar to my answer, good way too (maybe better). Another solution will be a multibinding with a multi converter.

Answer (score 1):

Put your SearchStrategy in your ViewModel and pass it using Binding. I don't know if I answer to your question, give more information

Comment: I'm a bit new to XAML and C# and only know some basics of binding. I don't understand what you mean by `Put your SearchStrategy in your ViewModel and pass it using Binding.` Can you please elaborate?